# Nested if with array formula Googlesheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to use nested if with Array formula but don't understand what is wrong.

According to my experience it should work.

Here is my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(G2:G="D",I2:I="Disagree")=true,"FP",IF(AND(G2:G="A",I2:I="Agree")=true,"TN",IF(AND(G2:G="D",I2:I="Agree")=true,"TP",IF(AND(G2:G="A",I2:I="Disagree")=true,"FN","")))))
```

What I am receiving is blank output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested if (to be accurate, `AND` and `OR`) is not supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`, you have to break it down to multiple levels of IF

CHANGE FROM: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(G2:G="D",I2:I="Disagree"), ...`

TO: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="D",IF(I2:I="Disagree", ...`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((G2:G="D")*(I2:I="Disagree")=true, "FP",
 IF((G2:G="A")*(I2:I="Agree")=true,    "TN",
 IF((G2:G="D")*(I2:I="Agree")=true,    "TP",
 IF((G2:G="A")*(I2:I="Disagree")=true, "FN", )))))
```